# Simple passing of Value from one Component to another through context

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native and would like to use Context to keep a socket connection alive between screens in the future. For now, I tried to learn the concept of context just to pass simple values around but the value doesn't get sent.

[Tried to follow the tutorial here, but by sending simple values instead.](https://itnext.io/how-to-use-a-single-instance-of-socket-io-in-your-react-app-6a4465dcb398)

I create my ValueContext in ValueContext.js here.

```
import React from 'react';

const ValueContext = React.createContext();

export default ValueContext;
```

Here's my LoginScreen.js where I set context provider.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ConnectionScreen from './ConnectionScreen';
import ValueContext from './ValueContext';

const testValue = 5;

export const sendValue = props => (
  <ValueContext.Provider value={testValue}>
    <ConnectionScreen />
  </ValueContext.Provider>
)

class LoginScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return()
  }
}
```

Then in my ConnectionScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Alert } from 'react-native';

import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen';
import ValueContext from './ValueContext';

export const receiveValue = props => (
  <ValueContext.Consumer>
    {testValue => <ConnectionScreen {...props} testValue={testValue} />}
  </ValueContext.Consumer>
)

class ConnectionScreen extends Component {
  showAlertValue = () => {
    Alert.alert(this.props.testValue);
  }
  render() {
   return(
     <View>
       {this.showAlertValue()}
     </View>
   )
  }
}
```

So after setting the value in LoginScreen, I would like to access it in ConnectionScreen. All I get in my alert box is an empty box with no values. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: to use `Context.Consummer` your component must be wrapped in `Context.Provider` => you should move it to wrap both screen in `createAppContainer`

Comment: Do you mean the AppContainer in App.js? Or in the return() function of both screen? I'm using react navigation and have my LoginScreen as my initial route.

Comment: yes, in there you can wrap both screen into a Provider

Comment: Hmm thanks for the input, but i'm still not getting any values out from my testValue variable.. Is it not possible to wrap context in functions that are outside of the components like what I did?

Comment: Hey @tuan.tran, I managed to solve the problem. It was due to me wrapping the wrong screen. I was confused about the initial route and the createappcontainer, and placed the wrapper in the wrong component. Thanks!!

Comment: Nice to hear that :))